Why can’t you reverse a hash?
I am new to cyber security and I do know the basics of password hashing works.
However, I have not been able to find an answer online to my query- although I think that it is a stupid and somewhat obvious one: if a hashing algorithm is used to hash a password, and (using the same hash alg such as md5) the same hash will always be produced from the same password, why can’t you just reverse the hashing algorithm to crack the hash?
Like I say, this probably a stupidly obvious question- but I just don’t understand!
If you have 2, being the password, and use the algorithm that is X3, then the hashed
password is 6. Then can’t you just reverse it and divide by 3, equaling the original password of 2?
Obviously, this is very much simplified, but anyone everyone and anyone has access to hashing tools- do they either not know the actual algorithm, or am I missing something?

Dupes: 1) Why can't we reverse hashes? 2) Why can't I reverse a hash to a possible input? reads 3) Differences between hash- and encryption algorithms? 4) Can I say "I have encrypted something" if I hash something?
